# Check the health of my SSD

Tags: 14.04, ssd

I want to check the status of my ssd under Ubuntu 14.04 so I use these commands:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Media_Wearout_Indicator
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

and this is the output:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-57-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     SandForce Driven SSDs
Device Model:     KINGSTON SV300S37A120G
Serial Number:    50026B774200F2E6
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0026b7 74200f2e6
Firmware Version: 521ABBF0
User Capacity:    120.034.123.776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS, ACS-2 T13/2015-D revision 3
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Aug  3 16:03:14 2015 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   1) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x79) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  36) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x0025) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0033   095   095   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0/2484744
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1149h+09m+10.840s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       469
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       27
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   041   046   000    Old_age   Offline      -       41 (Min/Max 14/46)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   041   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 14/46)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/2484744
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/2484744
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/2484744
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       1054
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       1463
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       1463
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       2663

SMART Error Log not supported

SMART Self-test Log not supported

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

I think that I have to change the ssd or make a backup, right?
The values `230 Life_Curve_Status` and `231 SSD_Life_Left` seem very bad, am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `231 SSD_Life_Left` value is 100 with fail threshold of 10.

Same is with `230 Life_Curve_Status`. The value is 100.

Actually these parameters look perfect.

Comment: yes, but the worst value for these fields is 100 (column WORST). The perfect value would be 1, am I wrong?

Comment: "Worst" means "seen worst with this drive". So it always has been 100. It is perfect.